# Highcharts Stacked Colum with variable dynamic number of values

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to draw a stacked Column chart based on this example :

```
             +--------+
             |    6   |
             +--------+
             |    1   |
+--------+   +--------+
|    3   |   |        |
+--------+   |    4   |
|    2   |   +--------+
+--------+   |        |
|        |   |    3   |
|    1   |   |        |
+--------+   +--------+
2014-03-21   2014-03-22
```

On each stacked bar, I dont have the same number of values. Ideally, that should be stacked percentage columns. Any idea ?

Comment: post your code and make a demonstration on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: That will be hard... I'm not even sure Highchart could do Columns like I want...

Comment: It's pretty straightforward in highcharts. If you don't want a value for one of the items, replace it with a null. You really need to display what you have tried first though, you can't expect people to code for you from scratch.

Comment: I think the worst thing is highcharts docs, they give only examples for predefined xAxis, and Series sorted by Categories. I'm trying dynamic xAxis with type='datetime' and Series with data sorted by date, not by Categories.

Comment: I agree with you @Duniyadnd, I will put a 'static' list of Categories, and set value to null if I dont want it to be draw on charts. Not the easiest way, thanks Highcharts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, closing thread.
The Highchart documentation is weak and dont give enough example on how I could do what I want, but ignoring the documentation and putting the series as I want is working.